# Convert multiplication in $GF(2^{128})$ to bitwise AND?

Tags: finite-field

Suppose we have $GF(2^{128})=F_2[x]/(x^{128}+x^7+x^2+x+1)$ and $a,b,c \in GF(2^{128})$ with $a*b=c$, where `*` is multiplication in $GF(2^{128})$. Could we convert them to $a',b',c'$ of length 128 bit vectors, such that $a'\&b'=c'$, where `&` is bitwise AND?

I think FFT might work, but I am confused how to do a FFT on a length 128 vector in $F_2$.

Answer (score 2):

> Could we convert them to $a',b',c'$ of length 128 bit vectors, such that $a'\&b'=c'$, where `&` is bitwise AND?

No.  There are $2^{128}$ elements of $GF(2^{128})$, and there are $2^{128}$ length 128 bit vectors, and so there must be a 1:1 correspondence.

Now, consider the $GF(2^{128})$ element that converts to the all-1 vector; call the element $A$, and call the bit vector that is mapped to (namely, the all-1 vector) as $A'$.

Now, we know that the $GF(2^{128})$ equation $B \times C = A$ has at least $2^{128}-1$ solutions in $B, C$, however when looking that the post-mapping and function, we see that the corresponding operation $B' \& C' = A'$ has only one solution (namely, $B' = C' = A'$).  Hence, we conclude that any such mapping cannot preserve the multiplication operation.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I got a new idea: if we have `a*b=c^d` in $GF(2^{128})$, is it possible to convert it to `a'&b'=c'^d'`. The arguments do not follow directly, and I am not sure if this is possible.